# Need Help button href in php echo

Tags: php, button, onclick, href

i have the following codeline:

```
//onclick="location.href='http://www.example.com'"
echo "<button type='button' class='single_add_to_cart_button button alt wdm_enquiry' style='background:rgb(0, 171, 0) none repeat scroll 0% 0%';>Ihre ".$post_name." Testversion anfordern!</button>";
```

The onclick need to include in the echo, but i cant do this.

Anyone can help me out?

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just write it like this:

```
echo "<button type='button' onclick=\"location.href='http://www.example.com'\" class='single_add_to_cart_button button alt wdm_enquiry' style='background:rgb(0, 171, 0) none repeat scroll 0% 0%';>Ihre $post_name Testversion anfordern!</button>";
```

Answer (score 0):

This didn't work for me, but I got it working this way

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'my_function_sample', 10 );
function my_function_sample() {
    global $product;

    echo "<button type='button' onclick=\"location.href='https://yourwebsite.com/shop '\" class='single_add_to_cart_button button alt wdm_enquiry' style='background:rgb(0, 171, 0) none repeat scroll 0% 0%';>Zum Shop</button>";   
}
```

Comment: What is change in your answer which is already given above